# Typescript: let module resolution (paths/base), dynamic imports and resolveJsonModule work together

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

### the problem

i am having some issues while trying to use typescripts module resolution with paths, json file imports and dynamic imports. this is what i have done:

- First: i introduced `"resolveJsonModule": true` to be able to import .json files
- Second: i introduced (used) dynamic imports (this is running fine)
- Third: i introduced modules (paths) like in the example below (here comes my problem)

I am not sure, if i am confusing some things here. But help would be really appreciated to be able to use the following three together:

- 1 dynamic imports
- 2 import json files
- 3 use typescript module resolution

### infos:

- my node version: v11.14.0
- i am able to use the latest node version, so no restrictions here

### the code:

```js
// 1. dynamic import
const subfolder = 'example'
let { ex } = await import(`./../../some/path/${subfolder}`)
```

```js
// 2. json file import
import config from './../../config.json'
```

```js
// 3. module resolution
// some/path/file_a.ts
import { example_function } from '@utils/ex'
...
const result = await example_function()

// src/utils/ex/index.ts
export async function example_function() {}
```

### the error:

The code above is running through the compiler and builds without errors.
But when i try to start the compiled code i will get an error like this:

```
➤ node lib/index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@utils/ex'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:668:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:591:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mod/cod/wo/thingylabs/calpobot/cb1/lib/utils/pipeline/pipelineRunChatops.js:52:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
```

### attempts to solve the issue

- i tried to change to experiment with the modules and moduleResolution but with no success

### my complete tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "pretty": true,
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@utils/fs": ["utils/fs"],
      "@pipelines/*": ["pipelines/*"],
      "@jobs/*": ["jobs/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem discussed here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24715
As a workaround, you can replace

```
import config from './../../config.json'
```

with

```
const config = require('./../../config.json')
```